# How do I install Terminator?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, terminator

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04. I tried installing terminator from `https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/terminator` **(The link is redirecting somewhere else now)** but I am unable to install it. I am getting following message

> This software comes from a 3rd party and may contain non-free components

How can I install terminator by command line?

Comment: The image in your question does not suit your question.

Comment: You might consider trying to install Terminator vir the software center instead so that you get the version for your release instead of trying to install the version for precise (12.04)

Comment: @DavidFoerster Reopened. VTC as dupe?

Comment: instructions in new repo: https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator/blob/master/INSTALL.md

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install terminator
```

Comment: You might also be interested on [Byobu](http://byobu.co/), for example [with Guake](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355145/209677).

Comment: This is (was) like using IE to download Chrome / FF. 

Comment: first you need to add new & maintained repo: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mattrose/terminator https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator/blob/master/INSTALL.md